# Connection stuck while using Samsung Remote Test Lab

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I want to track down a bug on Samsung Devices using Samsung RTL. Sadly i cant get that client to work on my System (macOS 10.13.1):

It just says `Connecting...`
Nothing happens from here.

[image: ctl client stuck at connecting]

Steps i did to come here:

- Downloaded and installed newest JRE from Website:
  https://www.java.com/inc/BrowserRedirect1.jsp
- Enabled Java for Browser and Web-Start-Apps in Java Control Panel
- Added `https://img-developer.samsung.com` to exeption list
- Checked for Port 2600 using Network Utility:
  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202790
- Create Samsung Developer Account
- Reserving an Device (Galaxy S6)
- Download `.jnlp`-File and run it

Comment: Can you clarify items 3 and 4 in list (adding URL to exception list and checking port 2600 - provided link is dead)? I'm struggling with the same issue now...

Comment: @DenRimus checking port: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202790
go to portscan - click scan.
i don't know anymore how i did that exception list thing

Comment: Samsung having Samsung-specific bugs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Customer Support has answered to me. Seems like i have just selected a bad device. I chose another one and it worked :)

Comment: I tried 6 devices for 12 credits, none of them worked. Only black screen.

Comment: Windows 10. Checked https://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/ to see 2600 port, it was always close. I tried 3 devices, only Galaxy S5 worked, After opening an application and several seconds later a keyboard freezed. Then I restarted a device, and it couldn't connect anymore.

Comment: @t0m did you press the unlock button?

Comment: I have this issue with a device I tried last week... so I guess either you're lucky, or I am not

Comment: Thanks for this answer, my first experience with attempting to use RTL ended up with a bad device apparently, as this happened to me. Based on your answer - even though it meant burning more of my daily credits - I tried with a different device, and though it did pause for a bit longer on connecting then I would expect, it did go through and I got a device. Cheers!